# Repeat Forms Rendering in Rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails nested form like this one below. What I'd like to do is to automatically render a certain quantity of phases forms depending on the value selected by the user on my main challenge form.

```
<%= form_for(@challenge, :html => {:id => "new_challenge_form"}) do |f| %>
    .
    .
    .
    <h3 class="color-gray small-padding-bottom">
        <%= t "challenges.form_labels.how_many_phases" %>
    </h3>
    <%= number_field_tag 'quantity', 1, :in => 1...10, :class => "text-input-wizard" %>
    <button> Generate Phases! </button>
<% end %>
```

I was trying to achieve this with some jquery but it isn't working. Something like

```
$('.block').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("phases/new")).html_safe %>')
```

What's the right way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Where is your `.block` element?

Comment: Inside of my challenges form.

Comment: If you post that, it'd be easier for someone to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Create partial with form. For mexample _challenge_form.html.erb in new.html.erb create div with class .block. 
Then create new.js.erb and move there js code

```
$('.block').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("phases/_challenge_form", :challenge => @challenge)).html_safe %>')
```